# Openni2 is 'No matching device found' with Kinect One(v2)

Tags: ros, kinect, iai-kinect2, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I use Kinect One(v2) with my ROS project, so I already installed iai_kinect2 and libfreenect2.

This works fine to me.

However, I want to use openni with my Kinect device, and it show me 'No matching device found'.

```
roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch
... logging to /home/cyc/.ros/log/75743bc6-43db-11e9-ba90-9c5c8e1afee7/roslaunch-cyc-X550JX-10898.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://cyc-X550JX:46521/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /camera/camera_nodelet_manager/num_worker_threads: 4
 * /camera/depth_rectify_depth/interpolation: 0
 * /camera/driver/color_depth_synchronization: False
 * /camera/driver/color_mode: 5
 * /camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url: 
 * /camera/driver/depth_frame_id: camera_depth_opti...
 * /camera/driver/depth_mode: 5
 * /camera/driver/depth_registration: False
 * /camera/driver/device_id: #1
 * /camera/driver/id_manufacturer: 1d27
 * /camera/driver/id_product: 0601
 * /camera/driver/ir_mode: 5
 * /camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url: 
 * /camera/driver/rgb_frame_id: camera_rgb_optica...
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES
  /camera/
    camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_points (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_registered_sw_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    driver (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_sw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
    register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
    rgb_rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
  /
    camera_base_link (tf2_ros/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link1 (tf2_ros/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link2 (tf2_ros/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link3 (tf2_ros/static_transform_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [10915]
process[camera/driver-2]: started with pid [10916]
process[camera/rgb_rectify_color-3]: started with pid [10917]
process[camera/depth_rectify_depth-4]: started with pid [10919]
process[camera/depth_metric_rect-5]: started with pid [10936]
process[camera/depth_metric-6]: started with pid [10944]
process[camera/depth_points-7]: started with pid [10962]
process[camera/register_depth_rgb-8]: started with pid [10977]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-9]: started with pid [10991]
process[camera/depth_registered_sw_metric_rect-10]: started with pid [11004]
process[camera_base_link-11]: started with pid [11019]
[ INFO] [1552294584.856946808]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
process[camera_base_link1-12]: started with pid [11045]
process[camera_base_link2-13]: started with pid [11066]
process[camera_base_link3-14]: started with pid [11080]
[ INFO] [1552294584.945483093]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: std::__cxx11::string openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Driver::resolveDeviceURI(const string&) @ /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-openni2-camera-0.4.2/src/openni2_driver.cpp @ 737 : Invalid device number 1, there are 0 devices connected.
```

I have tried everything I can try, but still doesn't work.

Anyone know that? Please help me.

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318198/openni2-is-%27no-matching-device-found%27-with-kinect-one(v2)/) by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2019-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a solution by myself, and hope it could help you guys !

1.Follow [this](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2) tutorials to install libfreenect if you use kinect v2.

2.Run the test openni step in the last line.

> sudo apt-get install openni2-utils && sudo make install-openni2 && NiViewer2

If you install successfully, it will show you a depth image and raw image in a window.

3.Run the openni2 launch

> roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch

You will see these error message and just ignore them.

```
[ERROR] [1552467844.769017052]: Unsupported IR video mode - Resolution: 640x480@30Hz Format: Gray16
[ERROR] [1552467844.769132239]: Unsupported color video mode - Resolution: 640x480@30Hz Format: RGB888
[ERROR] [1552467844.769336219]: Could not set auto exposure. Reason: void openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Device::setAutoExposure(bool) @ /home/cyc/catkin_ws/src/openni2_camera/openni2_camera/src/openni2_device.cpp @ 549 : Couldn't set auto exposure: 
    Stream setProperty(101) failed



[ERROR] [1552467844.769386920]: Could not set auto white balance. Reason: void openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Device::setAutoWhiteBalance(bool) @ /home/cyc/catkin_ws/src/openni2_camera/openni2_camera/src/openni2_device.cpp @ 565 : Couldn't set auto white balance: 
    Stream setProperty(100) failed



[ERROR] [1552467844.769438262]: Could not set exposure. Reason: void openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Device::setExposure(int) @ /home/cyc/catkin_ws/src/openni2_camera/openni2_camera/src/openni2_device.cpp @ 582 : Couldn't set exposure: 
    Stream setProperty(102) failed
```

This mean kinect v2 with openni do not support those function,but it didn't influence my project.
If anyone know how to fix it, please add it.

4.View in Rviz

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [A_YIng](https://answers.ros.org/users/40085/a_ying/) with karma: 37 on 2019-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0